# Testing database credentials Craft 3 Setup

Tags: craft3, composer, postgresql

When i try setup db in craft 3 at windows with composer using php craft setup/db command it give me

````
Which database driver are you using? [mysql,pgsql,?]: pgsql
Database server name or IP address: [127.0.0.1]
Database port: [5432]
Database username: [root]
Database password:
Database name: cmsdb
Database schema: [public]
Database table prefix:
Testing database credentials ... failed: could not find driver
Database server name or IP address: [127.0.0.1]```
````

Answer (score 1):

This might be the problem with the pgsql driver.

You need to install and activate postgresql extension in PHP

You can use below command to install it.

```
[sudo] apt-get install php-pgsql
```

For activating it, uncomment pgsql and pdo-pgsql extensions in etc/php/$PHP_VERSION/apache2/php.ini file.

After all this you need to restart you apache server and the try to connect again.